# Replace all breaktags with paragraphs?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm wondering if there is anyway for jsoup to be smart enough to figure out how to replace `<br>` tags with `<p>` tags around the lines of text.  For instance, here's what the text in a document looks like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur dictum ex. Fusce vestibulum lectus vitae diam venenatis, id scelerisque diam fermentum. Cras iaculis, ipsum aliquam convallis fringilla, lacus augue pulvinar leo, sed ullamcorper eros metus vitae nunc. Nam iaculis imperdiet quam nec pretium. Cras at purus ullamcorper, sodales nibh non, mattis nisl. Proin tincidunt augue a augue eleifend venenatis. Mauris ac urna vitae dolor placerat rutrum vitae quis sem. Maecenas laoreet fermentum consectetur.
>
> <br><br>
>
> Aliquam feugiat augue vitae aliquam feugiat. Pellentesque cursus turpis dolor, vitae tempor erat blandit nec. Donec viverra mi id leo feugiat, id euismod orci congue. Quisque nulla dolor, maximus pretium tincidunt vel, malesuada vel augue. Curabitur fermentum, eros non commodo pharetra, libero ante molestie turpis, at rutrum justo leo at ligula. Proin scelerisque congue urna id pretium. Donec pretium, ligula a tempor hendrerit, lacus augue molestie risus, sed sollicitudin dui massa at purus. Phasellus venenatis odio iaculis cursus commodo. Nullam porttitor nibh et viverra lobortis. Quisque eu ligula lacinia, tempus risus ac, vulputate ex. Ut scelerisque dignissim nisi vel dictum. In suscipit gravida pellentesque.

The text above doesn't have any paragraph tags...it's purely text (or html since anchor, strong, and em tags are used throughout) and break tags to separate paragraphs.

Is there any way to tell `jsoup` to:

- wrap the first line with a paragraph tag (starting `<p>` at `Lorem`, ending `</p>` at `consectetur.`)
- do the same for the second paragraph?

Then, I'd use the `element.remove()` method to get rid of all `<br>` tags.

Comment: It doesn't seem impossible to do it yourself. Interpret as a string, split on the br tags, create a new paragraph element with each token as the child. Hey presto.

Comment: Hi christopher, I know...that's how I did it for a news website we archived going back 18+ years...then I realized jSoup had so many built in functionalities I could have used to make my life simpler.

Comment: I used jsoup for quite a few things (like the 'remove' method), but it's too bad there's no built-in 'converter' for the process listed above.

Comment: There is no way to do this in a general case. A break defines a line break, a paragraph defines a logic block of text. There is no way to know what text a paragraph should wrap in general. Therefore you will have to do this yourself.

Comment: I use String.replace() method to achieve like this tasks, What is your html sample and where your trial code?

Comment: Hi JavaFan, yeah I ended up splitting the text using the break tags and appending starting and ending paragraph tags around each section.  Turned out great!  BUT...feels dirty knowing that any other process used jSoup and then I had to *settle* for plain ole' Java for that one process.